# Pansharpening radiance/reflectance of Landsat 8 in GRASS 7?

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing, landsat-8, pansharpening, bit-depth

first at all, I have to say that I'm **new GRASS user**.

I would like to make a pansharp in GRASS 7 with reflectance Landsat 8 bands. I have revised some related posts and blogs, and I didn't find out if it is possible to make a pansharp after in reflectance bands.

It seems that **i.pansharpen** only works with 8-bit data, however, Landsat 8 is delivered in 16-bit.

Is it necessary to do a r.rescale with reflectance Landsat  8 data before pansharpening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GRASS developer is currently trying to address this problem: A test version is attached here: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/2013-November/066354.html (see also the discussion later on in that email thread). As soon as an improved version of i.pansharpen is ready, I'll try to remember to post that here.

Meanwhile you could rescale your images with r.rescale as a temporary workaround.

Some material I have also posted here (maybe you have seen it already):
http://courses.neteler.org/processing-landsat-8-data-in-grass-gis-7-rgb-composites-and-pan-sharpening/

*Edit 2019:*

i.pansharpen has been updated to handle pixel depths from 2-30 bits. Released in [GRASS GIS 7.8.0](https://grass.osgeo.org/news/85/15/GRASS-GIS-7-8-0-released/).